# Passing an argument into a nested function that has been operated on

Tags: python, function, recursion, nested, arguments

I'm trying to iterate on the values x1,y1,x2,y2 by first, adding 16 to some x1 and x2 and then taking those values that have already been transformed under the while loop and operating on them again using new_row but move_row is taking the x1,y1,x2,y2 argument values and not the one that have been operated on.

My code:

```
count = 0
count2 = 0
def move1(x1, y1,x2, y2):
    def new_row(x1, y1, x2, y2):
        x1 = 0
        y1 = y1 + 16
        x2 = 16
        y2 += 16
        print(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        return (x1, y1, x2, y2)
    #image_creator(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    print(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    global count
    global count2
    while count <= 6:
        count += 1
        x1 += 16
        x2 += 16
        y1 = y1
        y2 = y2
        # image_creator(x1,y1,x2,y2)
        # print(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    new_row(x1=x1, y1=y1, x2=x2, y2=y2) # i want new_row to redefine x1,y1,x2,y2
    print(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    return (x1, y1, x2, y2)

def image_creator(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    global filename
    imgsmall = img.crop(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    new_filename = filename + 'small.jpg'
    return(imgsmall.save(new_filename))

move1(0,0,16,16)
# new_row is taking 0,0,16,16 as argument and not the new x1,y1,x2,y2 after the while loop
```

Comment: Why do you need to nest the function definition? You can keep the function definition outside and call it from within the other function.

Comment: What is your expected output ? Also, is it normal that you never store the result of `new_row` inside a variable ? For I see with your example you'll never get to execute the `new_row()` method with this example since the only way to execute it is to have `x2 == 12` which is impossible since you only add 16 and start from 16

Comment: @AndrewGrass I've tried that as well and I still found that new_row doesn't take in the updated values of x1,y1,x2,y2 after move1 is applied. I thought that this could potentially solve the problem

Comment: @BriannaGopaul I see, you don't have to define the `new_row` inside the `move1` function, your issue here seems to be more about how to get to actually execute `new_row`. Once we execute `new_row`, should we replace the original values for x1, y1, x2, y2 with the new ones or just print them out ?

Comment: @Plopp Do you mind elaborating more? If i'm returning ```x1,y1,x2,y2``` after they've had operations performed on them, why do I need to store the output - I assume the output is already 'stored' when they're defined as ```x1,y1,x2,y2``` in the function

Comment: @Plopp I want to replace the values.

Comment: @BriannaGopaul Okay, I see, let me write a small example ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue was that you actually never updated the values of x1, y1, x2, y2.

This is because while you are calling (after editing out the `x2 == 12` condition) the `new_row` function you actually never store the values it returns.

You have to store the result somewhere, for instance in the following example I am assigning the result directly inside the x1, y1, x2, y2 variable, the original values for this variables are now lost, if you want to keep the original values you have to define other variables to store the `new_row` result.

```
count = 0

def new_row(x1, y1, x2, y2):
   return (0, y1+16, 16, y2+16)

def move1(x1, y1, x2, y2):
     global count 
     while count <= 6: 
         count += 1 
         x1 += 16 
         x2 += 16
     # After the loop is done
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = new_row(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    return (x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

Also I took the `new_row` function outside of the `move1`, while it should work with it inside as well it has a cost: you will recreate the whole `new_row` function every time you will use the `move1` function. Because this `new_row` function is always doing the exact same thing defining it outside make it so that it will only be defined once.

I am not fully sure I did what you wanted so do not hesitate if somethings missing